# dd() not working in laravel shared hosting

Tags: laravel, shared-hosting, dd

I am having problem creating symlink in laravel shared hosting. First of all I did not think that the problem was with symlink() function itself. Later I noticed even dd() is not working. Note: dd() works in local environment.

Scenario:
I have created symlink.php file inside public_html folder which contains following code:

```
<?php
$val = "hello";
dd($val);
?>
```

While browsing domainname/symlink.php, i get the page is not loading(http 500 error).

Update:
dd() does work now. But still symlink not created.
Updated code below:

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/../stream/vendor/autoload.php';
symlink('/home/domainname/stream/storage/app/public/blogs', '/home/domainname/public_html/storage/blogs');
?>
```

Note:
1) app_url in .env file: http:\domainname.com
2) website is hosted without any other issue
3) I manually deleted bootstrap/cache/config.php because it invented other issues

Comment: So you call the php file directly? Then you are not using Laravel and so the functions are not available.

Comment: I presume you're getting "Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function dd()", thus the 500 status. I don't think the issue is related to symlinks at all but the obvious way to test is a simple script like `<php echo 'Hello, World!';`.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you didn't require the composer autoload file

`require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';`

The 500 error is thrown because the function

Comment: Thanks. It does solve dd() issue. But wonder why my symlink is not still created. I am updating my code.